# Clickhouse заходит в кафку по порту отличному от указанного в настройках

Tags: clickhouse, apache-kafka

В конфиге не указан порт, а только креды на подключение. В таблице clickhous'а указан порт, который нужен для доступа к топику kafka, я там выставил порт 9093.

```
/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml

<kafka>
            <debug>all</debug>
            <sasl_username>kafkauser</sasl_username>
            <sasl_password>Kafkapassword</sasl_password>
            <security_protocol>SASL_PLAINTEXT</security_protocol>
            <sasl_mechanisms>PLAIN</sasl_mechanisms>
</kafka>
```

А после создания таблицы ничего не происходит, данные не идут. В логах кликхауса написано, что тянуть нечего, но в топике есть данные, а в ошибках кликхаус при этом пишет, что на 9092 время на соединение истекло и брокер падает

```
CREATE TABLE test_kafka.tasks_queue
(

    `data` String
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = '10.10.10.22:9093',
 kafka_group_name = 'test',
 kafka_num_consumers = '1',
 kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
 kafka_topic_list = 'test2';
```

При этом в логах кликхаус пишет, что тянуть нечего, а в теме есть данные, а в ошибках клика, при этом, пишет, что на 9092 время на соединении все плохо и брокер падает, но в таблице указан порт 9093

```
tail -f /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log

2023.07.20 11:36:27.064262 [ 1281 ] {} <Error> StorageKafka (github_queue): [rdk:FAIL] [thrd:sasl_plaintext://10.10.10.22:9092/bootstrap]: sasl_plaintext://10.10.10.22:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#10.10.10.22:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT, 31 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

Конфиг кафки

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.10.22:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://10.10.10.22:9093
```

Я не понимаю, почему соединение идет на 9092, если порт явно указан для SASL

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.10.22:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://10.10.10.22:9093
```

Comment: В ошибке написано что падает совершенно другая таблица (похоже что это таблица из примера на сайте с документацией по КХ)